# open sqlite in BaseAdapter getview

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, android-custom-view

i cannot open database. it doesn't accept privateMode,... and without any mode it has error.

```
12-12 22:32:44.405: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1112): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1849)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:820)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:854)
        at com.example.easyshopping.CustomAdapterUpdate$1.onClick(CustomAdapterUpdate.java:73)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

CustomAdapterUpdate:

```
public class CustomAdapterUpdate extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater mInlfater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list;
    public CustomAdapterUpdate(Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list)
    {
        mInlfater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.list =list;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView ==null)
        {
            convertView = mInlfater.inflate(R.layout.updateapprow,null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.b1 = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnInsertToCart);
            holder.tv1 = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.updateQty);
            holder.tv2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.priceNewItem);
            holder.tv3 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameNewItem);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }
        else
        {
            holder =(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        HashMap<String,String> map = list.get(position);

        holder.b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                      SQLiteDatabase database = openOrCreateDatabase("ORCL",null);
                        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CART(id integer primary key autoincrement,title VARCHAR(150),qty INT(10),price INT(10));");
                        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO CART(title,qty,price) VALUES('" + holder.tv3.getText().toString() + "'," + Integer.parseInt(holder.tv1.getText().toString())+","
                                + Integer.parseInt(holder.tv2.getText().toString())+");");

                        database.close();

            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
    static class ViewHolder
    {
        Button b1;
        TextView tv2,tv3;
        EditText tv1;
    }
}
```

please help me how to open and insert data here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way..

database=context.openOrCreateDatabase("DatabaseName", context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

and also

```
Context context;

 public CustomAdapterUpdate(Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list)
    {
this.context=context;
        mInlfater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.list =list;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: i did what you said, it didnot work. it can not accept MODE_PRIVATE too